# Inheritence of common functionality for multiple classes with different base classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, pageobjects

In this solution there is a `PageObjectModel`, which contains page classes for each webpage in a set of three services to be tested. The page classes provide the necessary properties and methods for interacting with the pages.

Within each of the three services is a page which has an identical main body between the three services, but the surrounding pages are different.

If we call the common functionality `Foo`, there is a `FooPage` for each of the services, `A.FooPage`, `B.FooPage`, `C.FooPage`. My current solution for extracting out the commonality involves creating a common class `Foo` which contains all the functionality for that tool, and then creating an instance of `Foo` in each `FooPage`, and pointing to `Foo` methods from each `FooPage`:

```
public class Foo : BasePage
{
    public Foo(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver)
    {
        
    }

    public void DoThingOne()
    {
        // do something
    }

    public void DoThingTwo()
    {
        // do other thing
    }
}
```

```
public class FooPage : APage
{
    private readonly Foo f;
    
    public FooPage(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver)
    {
        f = new Foo(driver);
    }

    public void DoThingOne() => f.DoThingOne();
    
    public void DoThingTwo() => f.DoThingTwo();
}
```

and the same for `FooPage : BPage` and `FooPage : CPage`.

Ideally I would just have each of the three `FooPage` have `Foo` as their base class, but the issue is that they would lose all functionality contained within their service specific base pages (`APage`, `BPage`, `CPage`).

It seems logical to me that I would want `FooPage` to extend `Foo`, as `FooPage` really *is* a `Foo`, but `FooPage` is also an `APage`, `BPage`, or `CPage`.

Is there any way to cleanly go about this in `C#`, or would it be more messy after the fact?

*For clarity, each of `APage`, `BPage`, and `CPage` are extended from `BasePage`.*

Comment: Not sure what BasePage or APage do but you can make an abstract class with DoThingOne() as an abstract method. Inside that abstract method, handle the standard code all derived classes will share. Then you can inherit that abstract class inside your derived classes and override the abstract DoThingOne() method. Inside the override, do whatever is specific for the derived class then call base method.

Comment: @GHDevOps The methods themselves don't need to be abstract, as they are work independent of the different services, the key point is that each `FooPage` needs the functionality of `APage`, `BPage`, etc., while also getting the functionality of `Foo`.